# How to iterate through an Rails 6 object in a liquid template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, liquid

I need to iterate through a rails 6 object in a liquid template. Passing a single object works fine with a drop class (was quite a hacky way to set everything up without an up-to-date documentation, but it finally works). In my controller I pass a single object to a drop class like this:

```
@template.assigns['object'] = Drops::ObjectsDrop.new(@object)
```

But now lets say the object has many items which are accessible through @object.items . And each item has a name and a description. If I unterstood it right, I need a drop class for the items, too. But passing the whole array to the drop class like this does not work:

```
module Drops

  class ItemsDrop < Liquid::Drop

    def initialize(items)
      @items = items
    end

    def item_name
      @items.each do |item|
        @item["item_name"]
      end
    end
...
...
  end
end
```

How can I pass all @object.items to a item-drop-class to iterate over each item later on in a liquid for-loop?

Answer (score 0):

Finally this did the job:

```
@item_assigns = @object_items.collect {|x| x.to_drop}
@template.assigns['items'] = @items_assigns
```

And the following to_drop method in the model:

```
  def to_drop
    Drops::ImagesDrop.new self
  end
```